# Is it best practice to make functions failproof even though they can't be called in that way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a questionnaire that asks the user about their investment preferences. There are multiple chapters and each chapter has multiple questions.

I have a navigator component that has a next and a back button.

```
 <Navigator onNext={onNext} onBack={onBack} isNextButtonDisabled={**last question in last chapter is reached**} isBackButtonDisabled={**first question in first chapter is reached**} />
```

If my conditions in the disabled props are correctly set, thus meaning the functions won't be called, do I need to check for these conditions again in onNext and onBack or can I just ignore those, what is best practice?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for helping debug specific issues, rather than broader stuff like best practices, so this question might be closed. Just to comment, disabled buttons don't call their functions on click, so you don't need to check disabled status during the functions themselves, since they won't even be called in the first place